# How to align ggparagraph() text under tableGrob() in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, grob

## What I want to achieve

I am trying to implement margins in the `ggparagraph()`, but I can't find any settings which would help out. I tried setting both widths the same in `ggarrange()`, but this did not work and is a workaround. What would happen now when I export the PDF from the `ggarrange()` output is that the text is as long as the width of the PDF page.[image] I do not want to alter the width of the PDF page.

## Code

Here some sample code:

```
text <- paste("iris data set gives the measurements in cm",
              "of the variables sepal length and width",
              "and petal length and width, respectively,",
              "for 50 flowers from each of 3 species of iris.",
              "The species are Iris setosa, versicolor, and virginica.", sep = " ")
text.p <- ggparagraph(text = text, face = "italic", size = 11, color = "black")
stable <- desc_statby(iris, measure.var = "Sepal.Length",
                      grps = "Species")
stable <- stable[, c("Species", "length", "mean", "sd")]
stable.p <- tableGrob(stable, rows = NULL, 
                        theme = ttheme("mOrange"))

ggarrange(stable.p, text.p, 
          ncol = 1, nrow = 2,
          heights = c(1, 0.5))
```

I altered the code sligtly from this [source](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/print.php?id=177) to suit my needs.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `theme(plot.margin = )`. You can modify the numbers in the call to `units()` to get just the margins you are interested in. Note that `t`, `r`, `b`, and `l` stand for top, right, bottom and left respectively.

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggpubr)
text <- paste("iris data set gives the measurements in cm",
              "of the variables sepal length and width",
              "and petal length and width, respectively,",
              "for 50 flowers from each of 3 species of iris.",
              "The species are Iris setosa, versicolor, and virginica.", sep = " ")

text.p <- ggparagraph(text = text, face = "italic", size = 11, color = "black") +
            theme(plot.margin = unit(c(t = 0, r = 12, b = 3, l = 12),"lines"))

stable <- desc_statby(iris, measure.var = "Sepal.Length",
                      grps = "Species")
stable <- stable[, c("Species", "length", "mean", "sd")]
stable.p <- tableGrob(stable, rows = NULL, 
                      theme = ttheme("mOrange"))

ggarrange(stable.p, text.p, ncol = 1, nrow = 2, heights = c(1, 0.5))
```

[image]